# How to open and close streaming from rather channels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I installed rails 5 and start to create app with ActionCable. There are to much examples how to create "Dialog" app, but I don't found, how to work with 2(or more) channels, I mean, if I need 1 type of channel on the main page and 2nd type on the another pages, how to do that if user come to the main page - 1st channel is start streaming, when he come to another page - 1st is closing and opened 2nd type of?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested but maybe this could be an approach

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :uuid

    def connect
      self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
# app/channels/example_channel.rb
class ExampleChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed(data)
    stream_from "channel_#{data['uuid']}"
  end

  def unsunscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

Comment: From where you are passing param to this method subscribed(data)?